How to Bundle Custom Assets in Expo React Native App to Avoid Network Loading?
I'm working on an Expo React Native project where I need to include custom assets (specifically machine learning model files) in my app bundle. The goal is to have these assets bundled with the app so they are loaded from the local filesystem, not over the network, both during development and in production.
Currently, when I run my app, the first time these assets are accessed, it takes a long time because they are being fetched over the network from the Expo development server. Subsequent accesses are faster, indicating that the assets are cached locally after the first load. (I don't mind app size being large)
/assets/mlmodels/ggml-base.en.bin

What I've Tried:
Updated app.json:
I added assetBundlePatterns and packagerOpts to include all assets and specify custom asset extensions.
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Foo",
    "slug": "Bar",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    // ... other configurations ...
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "packagerOpts": {
      "assetExts": ["bin", "mil", "txt"]
    }
  }
}

metro.config.js
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

config.resolver.assetExts.push(
    'bin',
    'mil'
)

module.exports = config;

Used Static require Statements in Code:
I'm requiring the assets using static paths.
const modelBin = require('./assets/mlmodels/ggml-base.en.bin');

Created development builds in EAS.
Additional Information:

Expo SDK Version: 51.0.0
Development Build: I'm using a custom development client (npx expo start)

Any guidance on how to properly bundle these assets and avoid network loading would be greatly appreciated!
